# RTC to GIT migration using the third party tool

Tags: git, migration, rtc

We are planning to migrate from RTC to GIT in our project and decommission RTC post migration.

Please clarify my queries.

1) Can we perform complete migration to GIT using the tool in the below links or does it just links RTC repository to GIT,

https://github.com/rtcTo/rtc2git & https://github.com/rtcTo/rtc2gitcli -- is

2) if we can perfrom complete migration, please guide on how to proceed as i couldnt understand from where to run the migration.py file